# without last commas at output

Tags: php, csv

i have this code:

```
<?
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
      $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
      $html = array();
        while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
            $cat2['name_cat'].",";
    }
   }?>
```

I want to output categories without last commas! Thanks !

Comment: What do you exactly mean? I see you are explicitly adding a comma here.`<?=$cat2['name_cat'].",";?>`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: <?=$cat2['name_cat'].",";?>   show    actions, comedy, mystery,  and want without last commas !

Answer (score 1):

try this, after your while loop, use php `trim` function like this:

```
while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
            $cat2['name_cat'].",";
}
$cat2['name_cat'] = trim($cat2['name_cat'],",")
```

it will remove `,` from the end of your string

Comment: hey beside white spaces, it also removes all the character that is provided in second parameter to `trim` function. checkout the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: hey, you are storing the return value in variable `$cant` and you are echoing `$cat` the original string. do `echo $cant` in your code, you will get it

Comment: apologies all mistake were mine ... you are right its working and you can also try `rtrim`  http://codepad.org/vq2yNrNE to remove only last

Comment: @NullPointer yes `rtrim` can also be used.

Comment: what is not working? `trim` function with `,` as second parameter will remove `,` from the input string, if that is what you wanted.

Comment: `<?$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate)){
$kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)){
?>
<?=$cat2['name_cat'];?>
<?}}?>`    please insert you  trim in this code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");
while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate))
{
    $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");
    $html = array();
    $first = true;
    while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2))
    {
        if ($first)
            $first = false;
        else
            print ",";

        print $cat2['name_cat'];
    }
}?>
```

Comment: try again, a print was missing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$display = "";
while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2)) {
    if ($display == "") {
        $display = $cat2['name_cat'];
    } else {
        $display .= ", " . $cat2['name_cat'];
    }
}

echo $display;
```